# Remove suffix from cpack component

Tags: cmake, dpkg, cpack

CPack has a bug described here where monolithic builds include the build-directory path in the md5sums file for DEB packages: 
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16517

Since I'm using debian-stretch with CMake 3.7, the bug still exists for me and so I am trying to use the suggested workaround.

To work around is to enable CPack's components like so:

```
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL component_name)
set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL "ON")
```

However, then problem is that my package name changes when I do this from `mypackage` to `mypackage-component_name`.

Is there a way to inhibit `-component_name` suffix when building a non-monolithic build so that my users don't see a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  We need to set `CPACK_DEBIAN_<component>_PACKAGE_NAME`.  In my case `<component>=runtime`.

```
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL runtime)
set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL "ON")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_RUNTIME_PACKAGE_NAME ${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME})
```

Reference: 
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/CPackDeb.html